# Must I call atomic load/store explicitly?

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, stdatomic

C++11 introduced the [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) template library. The standard specifies the `store()` and `load()` operations to atomically set / get a variable shared by more than one thread.

My question is: are assignment and access operations also atomic? Namely, given

```cpp
std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
```

- Is `!stop.load()` equivalent to `!stop`?
- Is `stop.store(true)` equivalent to `stop = true`?

Comment: `stop.load(std::memory_order_relaxed)` and `stop.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed);` should be fine here, as Serge says.  You just need the store to be seen promptly, and `relaxed` still guarantees that.  You only need a stronger ordering if you need to synchronize other data.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

> Are assignment and access operations for non-reference types also atomic?

Yes, they are.  `atomic<T>::operator T` and `atomic<T>::operator=` are equivalent to `atomic<T>::load` and `atomic<T>::store` respectively. All the operators are implemented in the atomic class such that they will use atomic operations as you would expect.

I'm not sure what you mean about "non-reference" types?  Not sure how reference types are relevant here.

Comment: Equivalent to the versions of load and store without a consistency control parameter, that is.

Comment: @user1131467 - thanks. Removed the 'reference', well, reference ;-)

Comment: @BenVoigt All it means is that the most stringent memory order is used: `std::memory_order_seq_cst`. This prevents one from shooting oneself in the foot, but is possibly a premature pessimization.

Answer (score 42):

You can do both, but the advantage of `load()`/`store()` is that they allow to specify memory order. It is important sometimes for performance, where you can specify `std::memory_order_relaxed` while `atomic<T>::operator T` and `atomic<T>::operator=` would use the most safe and slow `std::memory_order_seq_cst`. Sometimes it is important for correctness and readability of your code: although the default `std::memory_order_seq_cst` is most safe thus most likely to be correct, it is not immediately clear for the reader what kind of operation (acquire/release/consume) you are doing, or whether you are doing such operation at all (to answer: isn't relaxed order sufficient here?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equivalent. The standard says in [[atomics.ref.ops]](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics.ref.ops):

> ```cpp
> T operator=(T desired) const noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to:
>
> ```cpp
> store(desired);
> return desired;
> ```

and

> ```cpp
> T load(memory_order order = memory_order::seq_cst) const noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Effects*: Equivalent to: `return load();`

Note that both `=` and the conversion function use `std::memory_order::seq_cst` as a consequence, which is the safest memory order,  but not the fastest due to the additional synchronization needed.

#### Why do we need both?

This is in part to create compatibility with C atomics. C11 added the `_Atomic` qualifier, so you could write code such as:

```cpp
_Atomic(int) x;
x = 0;
```

And exactly the same code would work nowadays in C++.
An explicit `load` and `store` is only necessary if you care about the memory order for performance reasons.

However, it is good practice to use `load` and `store` with a memory order consistently. This way, you can always express which memory order you intended to use. The operator overloads don't express this intent.