# c++11 equivalent of c# Interlocked.Increment

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm rewriting this c# code to c++:

```
public class LightOrder
{
    private static int internalIdCounter;

    public int InternalId { get; private set; }

    // i control myself to call this method exactly once for each order
    public void AssignInternalId(int ordersExecutorId)
    {
        // if InternalId is already assigned, i.e. != 0, i can print error or something
        InternalId = Interlocked.Increment(ref internalIdCounter);
        // more
    }

    // more
}
```

This works fine - each order has sequential id even if `AssignInternalId` is called from different threads parallel.

What is closest c++ equavalent to this code? Should I declare `InternalId` as `std::atomic<int>` and then just use `++`? Or I should declare `InternalId` as `int` and use something like `std::atomic_fetch_add`?

Comment: Using the MS C++ equivalent of the C# function is probably the best bet: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @sashang: I don't see why, when C++ already provides standard functionality for this in the form of `std::atomic`. [std::atomic::operator++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_arith) does exactly what is needed here.

Comment: @Mankarse: But how is std::atomic::operator++ imlpemented on Windows? If it's defined the same as InterlockedIncrement then that would be fine.

Comment: @Mankarse: Also InterlockedIncrement is closer in terms of translation between C# and C++ thane std::atomic::operator++ which is only in c++11.

Comment: @sashang i would prefer to use c++11 function instead of Windows API for better portability.

Comment: @javapowered: Yeah if portability is a concern this is true. If you want to compile with a VC++ 2005 then it's not. If you are concerned about the closest representation then it's not, and the question seemed to be asking about the closest representation.

Answer (score 5):

> Should I declare `InternalId` as `std::atomic<int>` and then just use `++`?

Yes.

> Or I should declare `InternalId` as `int` and use something like `std::atomic_fetch_add`?

No. Functions like `atomic_fetch_add` only work on atomic types (specialisations of `atomic`, or types like `atomic_int`), so you'd still need an atomic type.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is incrementing an integer, using just std::atomic will do the thing:

```
   std::atomic<int> internalId;

   public:
      void assignInternalId()
      {
         ++internalId;
      }
      int internalId() 
      {
         return internalId.load();
      }
```

Comment: No. As in the question, you'd have a static atomic counter, and a non-static non-atomic (and probably constant) variable initialised by incrementing and reading the counter.

Comment: Yep, that's true. You can see Yep, that's true. You can see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850752/) for more details